# Missing suggestion in VSCode in a script tag within an html file

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, intellisense, javascript-intellisense

When using `.style` method in vscode for javascript in a `<script>` tag in an `html` file, I do not get any code completion for some properties. I am typing `b.style`, but vscode doesn't show any suggestion. I don't know why it is happening.

[image: missing intellisense in script tag in html]

```
<body>
  <div class="body">
    asdasdasdasd
  </div>

  <script>

    let b = document.querySelector('.body');
    b.style   // <- no intellisense here for 'style'

  </script>

<body>
```

Comment: You have to install intellisense plugins. VSCode can't do it on it's own.

Comment: I have it. Still not working...

Comment: okay, it doesn't work in html files, but in which file does this intellisense works?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you have an `Element`.

> The Document method querySelector() returns the first Element

- from [MDN doc on querySelector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector)

and `Elements` do not have `style` as a property.

`HTMLDivElement`s do have a `style` property so you need to tell vscode that is what you have.  There are two ways to do that:

```js
/** @type {HTMLDivElement} */        
let b =  document.querySelector('.body');

let b = /** @type {HTMLDivElement} */ (document.querySelector('.body'));

// note the cast parentheses in the second version
```

If you do either one of those you will get the intellisense you want.

Comment: Is there anything that I can use for all elements in .js file ??